# Мужская кофейная компания

Tags: грамотная-речь

Слово *кофе* многие поколения грамотных людей считают принадлежащим к мужскому роду. Чтобы составить ему подходящую компанию, и другие слова с подобным морфологическим строением начинают употреблять в м.р. Некоторые примеры из Нацкорпуса :

> Владимир Шаров. Воскрешение Лазаря (1997-2002)
> Она то ли не знала, то ли умудрилась забыть, что на дворе почти двенадцать лет советская власть, и по утрам плакала, не понимая, почему прислуга **не подает ей в постель горячий какао** с круассанами и сыром бри.
>
> С. Вишенков. Испытатели (1947)
> Несколько минут спустя они сидели в натопленной столовой, растирали озябшие руки и **пили горячий какао.**

Популярное обозначение цвета : *терпкий бордо*.
Наверняка найдутся другие подобные случаи смены официального словарного рода. Тенденция?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Большинство несклоняемых существительных, внешне похожих на склоняемые существительные среднего рода (типа море и окно), относятся к среднему роду: ароматное какао, выдержанное бордо, пьянящее шардоне, горячее капучино, локомотивное депо, новое пальто, плетеное кашпо.

Слово кофе строгая литературная норма предписывает употреблять как существительное мужского рода: крепкий кофе уже остыл. Однако в непринужденной устной речи допустимо согласование по среднему роду: кофе остыло.

Нужно отметить, что из этого правила есть множество исключений, связанных с влиянием различных аналогий (таких как наличие употребительного склоняемого русского синонима; возможность подстановки склоняемого слова, обозначающего родовое понятие, и др.). Так, к мужскому роду относятся слова евро (т. к. большинство названий денежных единиц мужского рода, ср.: доллар, рубль, фунт, франк, тугрик...), бри, сулугуни (влияние родового понятия сыр), сирокко (влияние слова ветер), пенальти (влияние русского синонима одиннадцатиметровый штрафной удар). К женскому роду относятся слова авеню (ср. улица), кольраби (капуста), салями (колбаса) и др.

Некоторые слова могут употребляться в форме двух родов. К таким словам относятся, например, существительные, внешне похожие на склоняемые существительные в форме мн. ч.: выдержанный виски и выдержанное виски; армянский бренди и армянское бренди. Поэтому во всех сомнительных случаях для определения родовой принадлежности слова следует обращаться к словарям русского языка. Источник: Грамота.ру

Answer (score 2):

По поводу какао - это все-таки средний род. Я понимаю, что по аналогии с кофе просится мужской (плюс - шоколад), сама часто говорю "какао - он", но по правилам это все-таки средний род.
Да и бордо - вино. Наверное, все-таки тоже средней. Кофе тут как раз можно назвать исключением.

Comment: Какао - напиток, поэтому есть очень большой резон отнести слово к мужскому роду. *Вкусный какао* - звучит!

Comment: Есть такое. Но я посмотрела в инете - написано "какао, ср. род"